# edge split for uv mapping?

Tags: topology, uv-image-editor, normal-map

I am making a character, for game, making the UV mapping, the final question is at the final of this thread.

at the beggining I used traditional "t" mark's seams from the top of the head to the back of the neck , then press "unwrap" and gives me the classics UV, how ever I used "edge split" just to separate the head, as in this picture.

[image]

consider that the picture above , I ve "edge split" the face, the round form. then in edit mode I ve remove doubles (whenever use edge split, doubles vertices appears, always, so I ve removed them from the mesh of that area).

some cg artist would say me "just put few seams and if you want to get more resolution or pixel's density, just use whatever tool you need to get a good strectching ,reduce the island space" ...

but consider this experiment xD :

in the second image , I try to make the face larger , so the pixel density gives me more details. but I had Isolated the nose, mouth and part of the neck, I ve never seen this or made it , if seams will be visible, I will try to remove it in gimp or photoshop .

[image]

edge split for uv mapping? can this seams clever ? or method ? separate the nose, the mouth .

Comment: If you're using edge split, then removing doubles, you're actually welding the mesh back together. Also, you don't have to edge split to separate faces in UV. You can do that by selecting only the faces you want separate in the 3D view and moving them in the UV editor. I don't get the question, seems like you're asking for an opinion.

Comment: an opinion to make this experiment, for example separate the nose, the mouth and the ears ,cause I need some extra details in that area.